# Rails routing error. no route error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a resources :subscribers definitions in my routes file but I also have a action named validate in my controller. I'm trying to render a view to validate but I keep getting in error that says routing error when I put the address in the URL. I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong? I'll post my code for clarity.

CONTROLLER

```
class SubscribersController < ApplicationController
def index
@subscriber = Subscriber.all
end

def new
@subscriber = Subscriber.new
end

def create
@subscriber = Subscriber.create(subscriber_params)
if @subscriber.save
  flash[:success] = "Subscriber Has Been successfully Created"
  redirect_to new_subscriber_path(:subscriber)
 else
  render "new"
end
end

def edit
end

def destroy
end

def update
end

def validate
@subscriber = Subscriber.all
end

def show
end

private

def subscriber_params
params.require(:subscriber).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone_number)
end
end
```

View

```
   <h1>This is the form for phone number validation</h1>

<%= form_for @subscribers do |form| %>

<div class="form-group">
<p>
<%= form.label :phone_number %>
<%= form.text_field :phone_number %>
</p>
</div>  

 <% end %>
```

ROUTES file

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
 devise_for :users
 resources :subscribers, except: :show

 root "welcomes#index"

  post "subscribers/validate", to: "subscribers#validate"
```

That is my code, As you can see when I put /subscriptions/validate shouldn't it put up the posted view?

Comment: Possible typo? Your code uses `subscribers` but you call the route `subscriptions`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expected way to add a collection custom method is this...

```
resources :subscribers, except: :show do
  collection do
    post 'validate'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit confused where exactly you issue your request but this could be due to one (or more) of the following mistakes:

- you wrote that you type in your browser /subscriptions/validate but your routes are configured as /subscribers/validate
- you set the route as a POST request. if you type the URI into your browser and press enter then this is a GET request and not a POST